# How to get multiple objects from an array with an id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck with Javascript basics.. Working in Angular.

I have an array with objects:

```
 $scope.persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name:'jack'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:'John'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:'eric'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:'John'
  }
]
```

I would like to get the all objects that have same id with userId. So, loop through objects if the object id matches to user id select it.

```
$scope.getResult = function(userId){
   $scope.userId = userId;

   for(var i=0;i < $scope.persons.length; i++){

     if($scope.persons[i].id === $scope.userId){
       $scope.result = $scope.persons[i];
     }
   }
    $scope.userLogs = $scope.result;
 };
```

I get here only the last object which has the same id with userId.

How do I list all the objects that have the same id with userId?

Live:http://jsfiddle.net/sb0fh60j/

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
 $scope.getUsers = function(x){
   $scope.userId = x;

   $scope.userLogs = $scope.persons.filter(function (person) {
       return person.id === x;   
   })
 };
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sb0fh60j/2/)

Or, in your case, you need declare `result` as array before loop, and add matches to it, like this

```
$scope.getUsers = function(x){
   $scope.userId = x;
   $scope.result = [];

   for(var i=0;i < $scope.persons.length; i++){

     if($scope.persons[i].id === $scope.userId){
       $scope.result.push($scope.persons[i]);
     }
   }
    $scope.userLogs = $scope.result;
 };
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sb0fh60j/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly overwriting your result as it is no array. try this instead:

`$scope.result[] = $scope.persons[i];`

Answer (score 0):

rather than assigning you need to push that object to the array

```
$scope.result.push($scope.persons[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.result is not an array..

you have to declare a `var result = [];` and then you can do `result.push($scope.persons[i]);`

I don't understand why are you using `$scope.result`, it is useless to instantiate an attribute of the $scope and its watcher for this purpose, imho

edit: is useless also assign x to $scope;  added alse a jsfiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw5mp0zc/)